# Error Encrypt_key

Tags: magento2, migration

When I want to start migration for `config.xml`, I get a serious error message.

I have changed the Key sometimes, but the message is the same.

```
Key must be CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_KEYBYTES long
```

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the Screenshot from the terminal... When I change the key to more keys than there comes a message that its allocate maximum of 50 byte

**Did someone have an Idea about it?**

Comment: please attach screenshot

Comment: i have uploadet a screenshot...

Comment: Check in this file:
vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php:56:    
const CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_KEYBYTES = 32;